# ASP.NET 'CheckAllCB' checkbox header template does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using visual studio 2005 c#, and doing server side coding.

I have a checkbox template in my gridview. I have tried to assign a `CheckAllCB` button outside the gridview, so that when`CheckAllCB` is clicked, the list of checkboxes in the item template will be checked. 
However, it does not work and I am not able to spot the mistake. 
Below is my code for my `CheckAllCB` button:

```
protected void CheckAllCB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("CheckAll");
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("UserSelector");
            chkrow.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("UserSelector");
            chkrow.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**(SOLVED)**

---

Thus I tried using a checkbox checkchange in the header template. However, when the checkbox `CheckAll` in header template is check changed, nothing happens in the checkboxes in the itemtemplate.

Below is my code for `CheckAllCB` in header template

```
private void ToggleCheckState(bool checkState)
{
    // Iterate through the Products.Rows property
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("UserSelector");
        if (cb != null)
            cb.Checked = checkState;
    }
}
protected void CheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleCheckState(true);
}
protected void UncheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleCheckState(false);
}
```

Anyone can help me identify the mistake I did in my method? Thank you

---

`UserSelection` item template:
[image]

`CheckAllCB` header template:
[image]

---

Added source code for `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                     <HeaderTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAllCB" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllCB_CheckedChanged" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                          <asp:CheckBox ID="UserSelection" OnCheckedChanged="UserSelector_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can edit your post and include the gridview template? It would help to know how UserSelector is defined.

Comment: @competent_tech edited with ss

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more specific; can you include the ASP.Net page source where the grid view is defined (just the grid view).

Comment: @competent_tech Np. I have added the source code for my GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the checkbox is declared as UserSelection in the page, but you are looking for UserSelector in codebehind.

Also, the header is declared as CheckAllCB in the page, but you are looking for CheckAll in the codebehind.

You need to change one or the other so that the names match.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to spot my mistake for my `CheckAll` and `UncheckAll` button. It has worked now. But as for the checkbox `CheckAllCB` in the header template, is it possible to assign the same methods used in `CheckAll` and `UncheckAll` to `CheckAllCB` in the header template?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it on the client side. Here's how I normally do it with jQuery:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID='checkAll' runat='server' />

<asp:CheckBox ID='cb1' CssClass='checky' runat='server' />
<asp:CheckBox ID='cb2' CssClass='checky' runat='server' />

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('#<%= checkAll.ClientID %>').click(function() {
            $(".checky").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I agree that the client side is where this should go. I think your code needs to be wrapped in a document.ready() though.